# Keep duplicates in merge but not create extra rows in Python

Tags: python, merge

I have two dfs that I merged and both have 2400 rows. When I merge, I merge on:

```
df3 = hdata.merge(jdata.drop_duplicates(subset=['Address_SAS']), left_on=['Address Line', 'Identification Number'],
                                                                       right_on=['Address_SAS', 'Identification.Number'], how='left')
```

The issue is, both files contain duplicate addresses and identification numbers. Though there are duplicates in both data, I would like to match the hdata with the jdata and keep the duplicates but not create extra entries (so there should still be 2400 rows after the merge).

When I run the code above, the hdata that was merged has many missing entries (due to the `drop_duplicates`) but without it, it creates extra rows. When I count the number of unique ID's, `Identification Number` and `Identification.Number` should match.